# Pandas not replacing the string correctly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This my pandas dataframe:

```
print(top)
```

Result:

| Countries | Population |
| --- | --- |
| China[B] | 1376 |
| India | 1200 |

I want to remove the '[B]' from China, and for that, I ran the following code:

```
top['Countries'] = top['Countries'].str.replace('[B]', '')
```

But the result was unsatasfying:

| Countries | Population |
| --- | --- |
| China[] | 1376 |
| India | 1200 |

I also received the following warning:

```
C:\Users\walde\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8068/4262663465.py:1: FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version.
```

What´s wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'[B]'` is treated as a regular expression, which in this case means all characters within the brackets will be replaced (which is just B).

Use `regex=False`.